# Esper - catch delta events if no base event exists in data window

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

Let's say I have a named window:

```
CREATE WINDOW TestWindow.std:unique(FieldA) AS SELECT * FROM TestEvent;
```

Where `TestEvent` is a RevisionEvent, and `TestEventBase` and `TestEventDelta` are defined at the base and delta events of `TestEvent`, respectively.  The key here is `FieldA`.

Currently, if there is a delta event without a base event in the window, it appears that Esper silently discards this delta event.  So, for example, if a delta event comes before a base event, the state of the row in the window will look like the base event only, since the delta gets discarded.

My question is, is there a way to CATCH a delta event if it fails to go into the window to, for example, have special processing for when this happens?

If my application requires that I do not lose messages, and Esper is silently discarding some and not others, how can I be 100% sure that an event went into the window?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate statement to detect a delta event without a base event, i.e.
"select * from TestDelta as td where not exists (select * from TestEvent.first:unique(id) where te.id = td.id)"

Delta events are designed for use cases where the base event always arrives first and the delta overlays the base. If that is not the case perhaps use a named window and on-merge instead, or merge similar to the subquery above.

Comment: This solution requires Esper to store an event in this window in which to compare, though, yes?  If there are millions of messages coming through, this could be quite resource heavy.